# postfix, dovecot, virtual_mailbox_maps Mailbox format

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have installed on debian (wheezy) postfix and dovecot.

My mails delivers only if the file 'virtual_mailbox_maps' is in Maildir format:

```
admin@mydomain.com mydomain.com/admin/Maildir/
admin@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/admin/Maildir/
```

But earlier I had 'virtual_mailbox_maps' in Mailbox format:

```
admin@mydomain.com mydomain.com/admin
admin@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/admin
```

and mails delivered fine. But if I use Mailbox format now I get error

```
postfix/virtual[11364]: B95A52C0C19: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, relay=virtual, delay=12920, delays=12920/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/mydomain.com/admin: cannot open file: Is a directory)
```

Adding a slash at the end of each lines fixed issue, but this changes format from Mailbox to  Maildir.

In dovecot config file:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
```

So, what option I have lost in dovecot config or in postfix config?

I want to preserve the old way:

```
admin@mydomain.com mydomain.com/admin
admin@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/admin
```

without adding "/Maildir/" at the end of each line. If I add only a slash instead of "/Maildir/" at the end of each line then directories "cur", "new" and "tmp" creates at the "..../admin/" instead of ".../admin/Maildir/" and Thunderbird don't see my mails.

Comment: And why do you need mbox format instead of mdir?

Comment: Because in such case "/Maildir/" adds automatically and no needs to write it to the virtual_mailbox_maps. So, I write less. And real format (one file per all mails or one file per one mail) no matter.

Comment: The answer lies in the tidbit `cannot open file: Is a directory`. But actually, I'd suggest staying with Maildir if you don't have a very specific need for mbox; the old mbox format has a fair number of problems, not the least of which is the rewrites required whenever a message is deleted, which Maildir sidesteps completely because each message is stored separately. See for example [mbox: File locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#File_locking).

Answer (score 2):

Convert current maildirs to mailboxes according [this article](http://wiki.dovecot.org/Migration/MailFormat) on Dovecot wiki. There is a simple perl script for this task using `reformail` tool from `maildrop` package or `formail` from `procmail` package.

Then, switch Dovecot to deliver to users' mailboxes instead of maildirs with this directive

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
```

Remember that `%n` is used in maildir format definition and it is in conflict with new mailbox definition (error in postfix maillog) so you will have to rename the original maildir to resolve it. Finally, don't forget to reload related services to apply these changes.

Answer (score -2):

Just put

admin@mydomain.com mydomain.com/admin/

admin@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/admin/

instead of

admin@mydomain.com mydomain.com/admin

admin@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/admin

Comment: A bit of explanation would improve your answer